# Is there any R GUI not using client-server approach?

Tags: networking, gui, r

Most people uses RStudio, at least on Windows, but it has a problem, it connects to R using TCP, through 127.0.0.1 port 8787.

That causes problems in many computers, related with the antivirus, the firewall and  performamnce issues.

Sometimes they can be solved modifying the settings of the computer, but that's not always possible.

I think other GUI use the same approach.

Is there any other alternative?
With R embedded in the program itself or with other kind of communication between executables.

Comment: Do you have an example of the kind of problems you run into? 127.0.0.1 being the local loopback interface, it is normally never filtered by any firewall. Also preformance-wise, it should not be an issue for the amount of data transferred between R and the GUI. Actually, many programs are using local connections on that interface (e.g., Firefox, Thunderbird, ...)

Comment: What features does the R GUI need?

Comment: Similar features to Rstudio or Jupyter

Comment: Have you tried R without a Gui?

Comment: @john, yes, many years ago, but it's not very usable.

Comment: I guess all tools such as beaker, jupyter, zeppelin...  use the same method.

Answer (score 1):

[Rcmdr](http://socserv.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Misc/Rcmdr/Rcmdr-screenshot.html) is a GUI for R that meets the criteria. It is an R package. According to its author, [John Fox](http://socserv.mcmaster.ca/jfox/), it formulates R command strings and executes them using eval(parse()). It is an open source, R package [available on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcmdr/index.html) and can be reviewed by the user.

Comment: You might want to give a list of features which match the question, or will help the questioner.